# How to simulate pre-test post-test trial data in R or SAS

Tags: simulation, ancova, clinical-trials

I am in dire need of your help.

I have to simulate a clinical study where the primary endpoint is change from baseline. The analysis method used in an ANCOVA. I am interest in mean difference between groups and group means.

I need to simulate 200 patients randomized into 3 groups. The ancova model is adjusted for center, baseline and treatment group.

So I need to simulate : Baseline (post-test), treatment allocation, center and pre-test value

I need to have real values for each of the 200 patients because I will be doing imputation after I have set the post-test variable to missing.

I would also like to repeat this simulation multiple times. Please tell me how I can proceed.

Thanks !